# Cant use some AppCompat themes and attributes

Tags: android, eclipse, android-appcompat, material-design

I'm using the AppCompat Support Library, but I can't use some of the themes and attributes.

For example, when I try to use `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` I get this error:

> Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar'.

and when I try to use `colorPrimary` and `colorPrimaryDark`:

> Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimary'.
>
> Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimaryDark'.

What could it be?

my themes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#FF0000</item>
</style>
```

Comment: @Blackbelt i'm using themes.xml, just posted it.

Comment: @Edgar, Because You use NoActionBar. You can not noactionbar with colorprimary. Can you  change parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" ?

Comment: @mustafasevgi same error.

Comment: How are you integrating AppCompat? (=including in the project)

Comment: @FlorentAnders Imported the project from the sdk and added the reference to android properties.

Comment: I'm 90% sure that AppCompat is not included well. You must probably have made a little error somebody. Are you on Studio?

Comment: @FlorentAnders Eclipse. i was thinking the same, but i don't know what could be wrong.

Comment: Have you added the dependency to the AppCompat res and the AppCompat res depend on the AppCompat library in libs?

Comment: Try adding library reference in project properties(Eclipse).

Comment: @Harry I did, in fact, i can use ActionBarActivity and Theme.AppCompat.Light

Comment: so try @style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar in parent tag.

Comment: All, the problem seems to be in eclipse, i just migrated my project to Android Studio and this solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be in eclipse, i just migrated my project to Android Studio and this solved the problem.